# Excel to Sql 2005 from Win 7 x86

Tags: excel, sql-server-2005

I have to import excel to sql 2005 with a win7 os x86 it does not support DTS,SSIS,anything Import, Export is also not present in sql 2005 and there are millions of records that too in a very different rows like say after 50 records the cell breaks into 1 or 2 gives the subheadline and again too many records so there are millions of records how should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider posting a sample of the data for a better answer.

Simply, you should force the data into normalised tables, and then use your favourite tool to push them into SQL Server. If you have no additional tools, then you can use the Bulk copy (bcp) utilities to move large volumes of delimited or fixed format data into tables - fast.

You can, either:

- Export the workbooks into text files and process them with scripts into the form you require, or
- Use VBA or alternative automation techniques in Excel to generate the normalised tables to import into the database

You can learn about the process in [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: how do i normalise it?